# Relationship between docker0, Docker Bridge Driver and Containers

Tags: docker, docker-network

I was watching a [YouTube video on Docker networking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vb7U_9AO7Ww) and saw this slide:

[image]

And I'm trying to make sense of it. From the [`docker0` docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/):

> "*By default, the Docker server creates and configures the host system’s `docker0` a network interface called `docker0`, which is an ethernet bridge device. If you don’t specify a different network when starting a container, the container is connected to the bridge and all traffic coming from and going to the container flows over the bridge to the Docker daemon, which handles routing on behalf of the container.*"

But I'm still a little confused on the flow of traffic here. Let's say I install Docker on a new host. I assume `docker0` is created & configured at installation time. So now my host has this `docker0` ethernet bridge on it.

Now let's say I start a container on my new Docker host:

```
docker run -it -p 9200:9200 -d --name myapp myapp
```

Since I didn't specify a network driver, `bridge` is selected for me by default. According to the blurb in docs above, the container should now be sending/receiving traffic over that `docker0` bridge. However, in the diagram above that, the indication is that there's no traffic flowing to/from the bridge-based containers (C4, C5, C6) from `docker0`, **and I'm wondering: why?!** Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, that scheme is not fitting exactly what is happening. I didn't saw the video, maybe that "picture" is a snapshot of a concrete moment. Maybe we should see the video to understand the context.

Anyway, when Docker create `docker0` inteface, there are some iptables rules created using new chains (DOCKER and DOCKER-ISOLATION). By default, Docker containers are only accesible from your host. Then using `-p` option on docker run command you are mapping ports from your host to the container directly. Doing that you can reach certain port on your host which is really on the container. You can check the NAT table before and after running the container using `iptables -t nat -L`. You'll see the difference and the rule for the mapping.

And yes, the containers are created on the same network and they can try to communicate between them on that network. By default, the network range used for docker is 172.17.0.0/16 so your first container will be 172.17.0.2 the second will be 172.17.0.3 and so on. (172.17.0.1 is your docker0 ip).

Comment: Nice info. Note that first container starts on `172.17.0.2` (.1 is for the host itself)

Comment: Thanks @OscarAkaElvis (+1) - to clarify, I did post a link to the video in my first sentence above, and my screenshot was taken from 10:45 in that video.

Comment: Also, in the screenshot above, what is the difference between: (1) `docker0`, (2) the container's "bridge" and (3) the thing labeled `br-ee40a8236479`? Thanks again!

Comment: Right @Robert. Corrected

Comment: I looked at the video: docker0 is the default bridge in host 1, br-ee40a8236479 is the user defined bridge in host 2. host 1 and host 2 have some connectivity in underlay network. container's bridge refers to the fact that container is connected to default bridge or user-defined bridge.